# Vala, GTK :How do I perform UI operations from a different thread?

Tags: gtk, vala

I have a server listening for messages on a port running in a different thread. Now once it receives a message I need it to be displayed in a textbox.

1. Is there method like runOnUiThread() (which is in android) or equivalent in Vala, GTK?
2. Or else what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [GLib.Idle.add](https://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.Idle.add.html) to schedule something in the event dispatch thread:

```
Idle.add(() => {
  textbox.Entry = "foo";
  return Source.REMOVE;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

In contrast to many other Operating Systems, apparently you could  perform UI operations from a non UI thread. I could successfully change the text of an `Entry` from the server thread. Not sure if this is recommended though.

Comment: It's not. GTK+ is not thread safe. You're suposed to register a callback using `g_idle_add` to have some code called from the main thread. No UI work should be done outside of it.

Comment: This will bite you eventually.